# Android - Firebase integration: CORRECT google-services.json but WRONG firebase url

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services

I've been trying to integrate my Android app with Firebase. In my first Firebase app (test-26ee4), I had set up the app incorrectly because I was denied permission...

After reading this ([Firebase Database Permission denied with read/write permissions set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424544/firebase-database-permission-denied-with-read-write-permissions-set-to-true)), I deleted (test-26ee4) and created a new Firebase app (awesome-etc). However, I noticed that I was getting the same errors.

After placing a log inside MainActivity.java,

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Log.d("testing", mDatabase.child("1").toString());
```

I found that the reference is still pointing to my OLD firebase app.

```
10-16 12:00:06.882 14428-14428/com.example.twu.line D/testing: https://test-26ee4.firebaseio.com/1
```

The google-services.json reflects that the url should be awesome-etc, but I don't know why my Android app is reading from the google-services.json incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read what's within Google Services json? It specifies the android project's package name.

```
    {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "xxxxx",
    "firebase_url": "https://xx-zzzzz.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "nxjwjx-7f23b",
    "storage_bucket": "dkwncn-7f23b.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1jjsjwkd:xjdjejfb:sjwjsj",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.xxxxx.schwjxns"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.nixho.scheduled",
            "certificate_hash": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "zxxxent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.blah",
            "certificate_hash": "xxxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "xxxx"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I recommend replacing the json because it's specific to each project you create else you won't be able to have firebase working properly

EDIT

**public static DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"); // We'll have to utilize the new Firebase 3.0 APIs
**

That's important

Comment: Hey Nicolas, when I created a new Firebase app (awesome-etc), I removed the old google-services.json completely and added a new google-services.json into the app/ directory

Comment: Simply follow the new content I've added! Let me know if there's any problems again

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twu.line/com.example.twu.line.MainActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid URL (https://awesome-etc.firebaseio.com/) passed to getReference().  URL was expected to match configured Database URL: https://test-26ee4.firebaseio.com

Comment: Interesting... I feel like we are getting closer to the issue.

Comment: hace you added the correct packages on the gradle file

Comment: yep     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'

Comment: Look for your old url in your project and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Ugh so I figured out that after deleting a module and resyncing, it worked fine... -___- sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: It's okay! At least you asked