# Android - Firebase rules read permission issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need help with Firebase read Rules.

this is the structure of my database

```
db:{

user:{

  uid0:{
    name:"mario",
    lastname:"super"
  }

  uid1:{
    name:"bubu",
    lastname:"gogo"
  }

  uid1:{
    name:"fajio",
    lastname:"mkokd"
  }
}
}
```

my rules:

```
{
 "rules": {

   "user":{
     "$uid":{
        ".read":"auth.uid === $uid", 
     }
   }

 }
 }
```

With rules simulator there are not problem to read user's info.

In my activity im using recycler view for populate list with user's name but 
i get Permission Denied.

WHat's te problem?? What's wrong??

this is my query for populate list

`Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");`

EDIT:

```
`10-28 17:28:22.680 8317-8387/com.scidaconnectpeople.www.scida W/SyncTree:     Listen at /user failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
10-28 17:28:22.680 8317-8317/com.scidaconnectpeople.www.scida    W/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:     Firebase Database error: Permission denied
                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at    com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAda   pter.java:199)
                                                                                         at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter$1.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:116)
                                                                                         at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.notifyCancelledListeners(FirebaseArray.java:119)
                                                                                         at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.onCancelled(FirebaseArray.java:99)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaip.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakn.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)`
```

Comment: db is a node on your firebase?

Comment: db is the reference of firebase database

Comment: try to add rule for write too, `write:true` or `write==$uid`. I have not tried it but you can test

Comment: the problem is reading data not write

Comment: Then please describe your error properly! show us the proper error

Comment: The problem is the permission denied error when i try to populate recyclerview. The rules i think they are correct because with the simulator i have access to userdata, but maybe there is somthing wrong in the query that im using to populate recyclerview

Comment: I understand your feelings but show me the logcat of your studio where it log the error, Update your Question for it

Comment: look at my logcat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database security rules are enforced on the level where you try to attach the query. Since you attach a query on `/users`, that's where it checks if you have read permission. Since you don't have read permission on `/users`, the query is rejected/cancelled.

This is often unexpected to developers new to Firebase. We call it "rules are not filters", both [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: thank you very much..I've understand the problem..now i need to study !

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of chances that problem you are facing due to `google-services.json`.

please confirm that you have downloaded updated json file.

Check these [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: i confirm..if i set .read:true global the recycler view work fine

Comment: @MorbusMorbus then its clearly means, problem was in rules and json file:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424544/firebase-database-permission-denied-with-read-write-permissions-set-to-true

Comment: i've downloaded ed updated json but does not work ...i think there is something wrong in my query...i dont know. ty for help