# DatabaseError: Permission denied firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am new to firebase. I want to read/write data with firebase in my app but when I try to do so I am getting this `DatabaseError: Permission denied`  error.

Rules file on firebase

```
{

"rules": {
    "sos":{
          ".read":"auth != null",
          ".write":"auth != null"
          }
}
}
```

Code file

```
        Firebase authFirebaseRef = new Firebase(ApiConstants.FIREBASE_MY_URL);
        authFirebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(AppConstants.FBT, authResultHandler);

Firebase.AuthResultHandler authResultHandler = new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        Log.v("onAuthenticated", authData.getUid());
        addEvents();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.v("onAuthenticationError= ", "FirebaseError= " + firebaseError.toString());
    }
};

private void addEvents() {

    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("sos").child("emergencyservices");
    mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            emergencyServicesList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.v("onDataChange", ":" + dataSnapshotChild.child("emergencyServicesName").getValue());
                EmergencyServiceModel emergencyServiceModel = new EmergencyServiceModel();
                emergencyServiceModel.setEmergencyServiceId(dataSnapshotChild.child("emergencyServicesId").getValue().toString());
                emergencyServiceModel.setEmergencyServiceName(dataSnapshotChild.child("emergencyServicesName").getValue().toString());
                emergencyServicesList.add(emergencyServiceModel);
            }
            loadDataToRecyclerView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.v("DatabaseError", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Earlier I added few records in `sos/emergencyservices` by keeping `.true` to `read/write`. But now I have to change it with authentication.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424544/firebase-database-permission-denied-with-read-write-permissions-set-to-true

Comment: did you enable sign in from console ?

Comment: @akshay_shahane Yes I already did it

Comment: after updating the rule have you replaced googleservices.json with the new one ?

Comment: Can you please provide me a link where this step is mentioned?

Comment: @akshay_shahane I think that is not required on rules update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using different firebase object for auth and a different one for query.
Try this

```
authFirebaseRef.getRoot().child("sos/emergencyservices"‌​).addValueEventListe‌​ner(new ValueEventListener() { ... };
```

instead of

```
mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("sos").child("emergencyservic‌​es");
mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ... };
```

Also, you are using the old version of firebase API. I refer you this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android). The document guides you through upgrading your existing Firebase.com app to the new Firebase console and APIs.

Comment: Do go through the documents. Upgrading to new fire base will make your work easier, efficient, and updated technically. And, you will find a ton of resources too.

Comment: Ok sure. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

We have one more source of the "Permission denied" errors, as of end of 2018.

Google has just introduces Cloud Firestore BETA.

The point is it's interface is the same as for Firebase, there is only one dropdown selector to separate both databases ...

Have spent 8h faiting with error, finally have found the default console view is a Cloud Firestore BETA view but not Firebase.

So my app talked to Firebase while I was configuring Cloud Firestore BETA.

8h lost .... Thank you Google ...

Comment: This was my poroblem too, after I configured the rules for the realtime database and not the cloud store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the user is signed in before attaching the listener. Since you're already listening for the authentication state, it's a matter of moving the code that attaches the listener into the `onAuthenticated` callback:

```
Firebase.AuthResultHandler authResultHandler = new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        Log.v("onAuthenticated", authData.getUid());
        addEvents();

        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("sos").child("emergencyservices");
        mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                emergencyServicesList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.v("onDataChange", ":" + dataSnapshotChild.child("emergencyServicesName").getValue());
                    EmergencyServiceModel emergencyServiceModel = new EmergencyServiceModel();
                    emergencyServiceModel.setEmergencyServiceId(dataSnapshotChild.child("emergencyServicesId").getValue().toString());
                    emergencyServiceModel.setEmergencyServiceName(dataSnapshotChild.child("emergencyServicesName").getValue().toString());
                    emergencyServicesList.add(emergencyServiceModel);
                }
                loadDataToRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.v("DatabaseError", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.v("onAuthenticationError= ", "FirebaseError= " + firebaseError.toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I am doing the same. Please see edited code

Comment: Hmm.... not sure what's going on then. The error message should tell you what location it's failing on.

Comment: getDetails() gives the same info Permission denied

Comment: Can you provide your log messages(all related to this problem) too?

Comment: Permission denied is the only message, I get

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you **enable the required sign-in method** in firebase console?

[image: firebase_signin_method]

Comment: Yes I did it using custom JWT firebase integration

Comment: You sure, onAuthenticated ( ) method is called?

Comment: Yes it is called.

Answer (score -1):

It is related to database so in firebase console  get in database and set rules to true for read/write